# What part of this request can be logged?

Tags: web-browser, proxy, logging

While testing a website i noticed a weird behaviour. When resetting the password a POST request with empty body is generated. The request is the following:

`POST /reset/token/[token]/passwhord-hash`

Now my question is: If google or any third party will intercept this request, will it also be able to log the password-hash and reset token?

Comment: If it is intercepted, then yes. But how are you expecting it to be intercepted? It's sent over TLS, right?

Comment: For example if you leave facebook opened while you reset the password or if google sniff your traffic and it get saved into google search engine. Yes over TLS. Would it be worse if the password is sent as plain/text?

Comment: "facebook opened while you reset the password" huh? "google sniff your traffic" - how? And if over TLS, then all they would see is encrypted text. How on earth would it be indexed on a search engine?

Comment: How does facebook and google knows everything about you? That's because they always try to look at what you are doing online. Also possible to leak it as referer?

Comment: @Pong TLS will encrypt the request path, so they wouldn't be able to see your reset token or hash.

Comment: I don't get the sense of having an empty post request when all parameters are set as get request and post body is empty.

Comment: And you think they know by inspecting traffic? They look at what you do openly and in public.

Comment: I think you have a few wrong assumptions here and you have combined them together. Empty POST request: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4191593/is-it-considered-bad-practice-to-perform-http-post-without-entity-body And the "interception" part is not based on an understanding of how "google or any thrird party" works.

Answer (score 1):

> Now my question is: If google or any third party will intercept this
>   request, will it also be able to log the password-hash and reset
>   token?

Sure,if google or third party sits between you and the network and somehow is able to break ssl/tls then they get all the clear text transmission,you are toast at that point,Not sure how the particular request has anything to do with it.

> How does facebook and google knows everything about you? That's
>   because they always try to look at what you are doing online

Probably not how that works.Although facebook was [caught](https://www.theverge.com/2019/1/29/18202880/facebook-research-enterprise-root-certificate-onavo-techcrunch) once trying to get people to install root CA by paying 20$,lol